# Apollo GraphQL iOS. Remove operationName

Tags: ios, swift, graphql, apollo

I’m having an error “request is not valid” and the message is “[operationName] is not permitted”

Is there a way to remove operationName in request body when requesting?

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: Hi Michel, thank you for the response. operationName is a default value that I need to remove. There’s no code yet (asking if possible in theory or how to do it) thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah already have this answer here https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-ios/issues/2998